# source insight multiple highlights

Tags: highlighting, source-insight

Is there some feature/macro readily available which can help in highlighting different words in source insight in different colours ( The original installation allows highlighting of different words, but all in the same colour).

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, but no solution yet!   : (

Answer (score 2):

I am looking for the same thing. But from the source insight official reference, although we can reset the style of highlight, there is no place to reset highlight style for multi words.

[link of official command reference about highlight](http://www.sourceinsight.com/docs35/ad919011.htm)

[image: snapshoot of resetting highlight style]

Answer (score 1):

Right-click in editor > **File Type and Language** > **File Type Options**(or Alt + Y) and check  "**Highlight references to selected symbol**" option

[image]